# I'm trying to get the date of monday before 1 of actual month

Tags: java, dayofweek, java.util.calendar

Java don't execute some lines of my code when I use Calendary library.

I'm trying to get the date of monday before 1 of actual month.

```
//Today is Tuesday, 2 January of 2019 (29/01/2019)

Calendar cp1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cp1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); //THIS LINE DON'T WORKS
cp1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format (cp1.getTime()));
```

//  return 28/01/2019 instead of 31/12/2018.

IF I ADD `System.out.println(cp1)` after line 2 java don't jump line 2 and works well.

```
//Today is Tuesday, 2 January of 2019 (29/01/2019)

Calendar cp1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cp1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); //THIS LINE WORKS NOW
System.out.println (cp1.getTime());
cp1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format (cp1.getTime()));
```

//return 31/12/2018 that is the correct date.

//Why java didn't execute 2nd line in my first code? Is a java bug?

Expected result "31/12/2018".
Actual result "28/01/2019".

Comment: I ran your second part of the code and to me it also returns "28/01/2019". I'd also suggest you edit your question and try express a bit better what you mean by _I'm trying to get the date of monday before 1 of actual month_

Comment: Sorry, I'm noob. For my, first part of my code returns 28/01/2019, second part returns for me "31/12/2018". However, "28/01/2019" is wrong. The correct result is "31/12/2018". Why java don't execute second line?

Comment: 2019-01-28, 2018-12-31 are both Monday. your Day of month is overridden by Monday. If you want 12/31 then should set the month to Dec and 5th week

Comment: The `return 31/12/2018 that is the correct date.` is not reproductible, I suggest you to test again https://ideone.com/IjE3X8
 , both does the same

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCB4vuh70XE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: https://ideone.com/a5Tq6I

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Ok, I will start to change all my classes.

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly recommand to use `java.time` as it's easier to deal with.

Use the [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementation found in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class. Pass a [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum object for your desired day-of-week.

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate mondayBefore1OfMonth = now.withDayOfMonth(1)
                                    .with(TemporalAdjusters.previous(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));

System.out.println(mondayBefore1OfMonth); // 2018-12-31
```

---

For your problem (reproductible as https://ideone.com/ph73wK
 ), it seems that if you don't make a call to the private method `computeTime()`the field `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` is overriden or something like that, by making a call to `.getTime()` or `.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` it'll update the date and you'll get good result

Comment: My java code have 1046 java classes in 92 packages. Is hard for me do this changes now. I've been using this library for years. I don't understand why is failing now.

Comment: @Hammerin87 And you got this at multiple places ?

Comment: No, only in my pc. Wait, i will upload a video.

Comment: check it now. ideone.com/a5Tq6I

Comment: @Hammerin87 yep yep, updated my post with what I understand, but don't know more

Comment: Ok, sorry. It's my second post.